# Adding a button with default appearance but changed background color

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

I have a linear layout where I am programatically adding buttons. I want these buttons to have the default appearance and behaviour (floating, shadow etc) of a button except that I want to change the main color.

This is what I've tried

```
val newContext = ContextThemeWrapper(baseContext, R.style.PrimaryColoredButton)
val button = Button(newContext)
button.text = "test"
```

my `styles.xml` contains the following code

```
<style name="PrimaryColoredButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

However this doesn't change the color of my button but gives the default color.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 
`android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"` but sadly, it just can be used in Android API 21+

If you want to change the button on Android API level below 21.
You can use use AppCompatButton using app namespace instead of android for backgroundTint. So it gonna be like this `app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"` .

For example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
android:id="@+id/my_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="My Button"
app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a shape background like this.

```
<ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="40dp"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
      android:stateListAnimator="@anim/btn_elevation" 
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:elevation="1dp"
      android:text="My Button"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
```

@drawable/btn_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">

 <!-- this will change your button bg -->
   <solid
        android:color="@color/color_white" />

<!-- this will give your button a surrounding stroke -->
<stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/color_accent" />

 <!-- this will give your button rounded corners -->
   <corners
        android:radius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

@anim/btn_elevation.xml (if u don't need it, remove from main button):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_pressed="true">

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:valueFrom="2dp"
        android:valueTo="6dp"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</item>

<item>
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:valueFrom="6dp"
        android:valueTo="2dp"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
 </item>

  </selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new [Material Button](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/) you have 2 options:

1. Using the `backgroundTint` attribute.

Something like:

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle"
 parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/button_selector</item>
    //..
</style>
```

2. It is the best option in my opinion. If you want to override some theme attributes from a default style then you can use new **`materialThemeOverlay`** attribute.

Something like:

```
<style name="MtButtonStyle"
 parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
   <item name=“materialThemeOverlay”>@style/GreenButtonThemeOverlay</item>
</style>

<style name="GreenButtonThemeOverlay">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

It requires the `'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'.`